# First class is ignored when second class is added - CSS

Tags: html, css, class

I'm new to CSS (actually, every time I tried to learn web development I dropped because of it). I'm writing the Survey Form from FCC and decided to play with it a bit to challenge myself.

As the title says, apparently whenever I add the class `radio-inputs` to a `div`, having as a first class `user-input`, the styles from `user-input` and `input, select` just disappear. It must be something about selector specificity, but I really can't figure it out.

```js
function myFunction() {
  dropDownMenu = document.getElementById("dpwn");
  dropDownMenu.classList.toggle("dropdown")
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&family=Sofia+Sans&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --transparent: #00000000;
  --white: #F5F5F5;
  --main-background: #F4F6F7;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, black, var(--transparent) 28%), url("./survey.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

main {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: var(--main-background);
  display: flex;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#title-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2rem;
  bottom: 4rem;
  margin: .2rem .3rem;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 0.1rem 1rem;
  /* background-color: rgb(19, 19, 19); */
}

#title-wrapper>h1 {
  max-width: fit-content;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'Sofia Sans', sans-serif;
  color: var(--white);
  font-size: 64px;
  line-height: 1.7;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#title-wrapper>p {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: var(--white);
}

label {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

--------------------------------
/* Styles defined here are disappearing :( */

input,
select {
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 43px;
  text-indent: 1rem;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: var(--white);
}

select {
  text-align: center;
  text-align-last: center;
  /* webkit*/
}

.dropdown {
  transition: .1s ease-out;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
}

option {
  text-align: left;
  /* reset to left*/
}

fieldset {
  display: flex;
  border: 0;
  gap: .5rem;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.user-input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.user-input>label {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.user-input.radio-inputs {
  display: flex;
  <--- works,
  but doing so styles reset flex-direction: row;
}

----------------------------------------------- #email-age>div:first-of-type {
  width: calc(75%);
}

#email-age>div:last-of-type {
  width: calc(25%);
}
```

```html
<div id="title-wrapper">
  <h1>Survey Form</h1>
  <p>Share your thoughts with us!</p>
</div>

<main>

  <form action="">

    <fieldset id="name-surname">

      <div class="user-input" id="name">
        <label for="user-name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="user-info" placeholder="Name" />
      </div>

      <div class="user-input" id="surname">
        <label for="user-surname">Surname</label>
        <input type="text" name="user-info" id="user-surname" placeholder="Surname">
      </div>

    </fieldset>

    <br>

    <fieldset id="email-age">

      <div class="user-input">
        <label for="">Email</label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
      </div>

      <div class="user-input">
        <label for="">Age</label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Age">
      </div>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <div class="user-input">
        <label for="dpwn">How satisfied are you with out product?</label>
        <select name="" onclick="myFunction()" id="dpwn">
          <option value="1" disabled selected>Choose an option</option>
          <option value="2">Very unsatisfied</option>
          <option value="3">Somewhat unsatisfied</option>
          <option value="4">Neutral</option>
          <option value="5">Somewhat satisfied</option>
          <option value="6">Very satisfied</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>


    <fieldset>
      <!--            **The problem is here!**
                    <div class="user-input radio-inputs">    
                        <input type="radio" name="frequency" id="">
                        <input type="radio" name="frequency" id="">
                        <input type="radio" name="frequency" id="">
                        <input type="radio" name="frequency" id="">
                        <input type="radio" name="frequency" id="">
                    </div>
                </fieldset>

-->

  </form>
</main>
```

I tried using `!important`, using the developer tools to experiment with different behaviour when applying inline-styles, everything (that I've tried) led to the styles being ignored.

Comment: Show this example in a codesandbox. A full example. Note: styles don't disappear. They get overridden in this order. Tag, class, id,

Comment: @Steve, for many - if not quite *most* - front-end questions we have a built in sandbox (the Stack Snippets editor, [Stack Snippets guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/82548)). If you request that someone create a 'code sandbox' please consider directing them to that tool (and editing the post yourself, to show how it might be done).

Comment: I've created a codepen here: https://codepen.io/davidtozz/pen/GRXWaOp

The image is local, so can't help with that

Comment: It's likely a specificity issue. Elements (e.g. input, select) have least specificity whereas class names have higher specificity.  See [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) for info

Comment: So basically i should put those styles inside the class user-input, right?

Comment: From that example - I have removed - user-input class and it is the same. So I don't understand the problem

Comment: @SteveTomlin This is even weirder.. Removing classes from that div gives me that "reset", while preserving user-input doesn't. I don't get it 
To recap, i wanna add radio-inputs, while keeping the styles that other input elements on the page have. I'll try to shift those values inside the 'user-input' class and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If there are two or more CSS rules that point to the same element, the selector with the highest specificity value will "win", and its style declaration will be applied to that HTML element.

Think of specificity as a score/rank that determines which style declaration is ultimately applied to an element.

Try replacing the ".user-input.radio-inputs" class with just ".radio-inputs" and then add important like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  dropDownMenu = document.getElementById("dpwn");
  dropDownMenu.classList.toggle("dropdown")
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&family=Sofia+Sans&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --transparent: #00000000;
  --white: #F5F5F5;
  --main-background: #F4F6F7;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, black, var(--transparent) 28%), url("./survey.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

main {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: var(--main-background);
  display: flex;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#title-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2rem;
  bottom: 4rem;
  margin: .2rem .3rem;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 0.1rem 1rem;
  /* background-color: rgb(19, 19, 19); */
}

#title-wrapper>h1 {
  max-width: fit-content;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'Sofia Sans', sans-serif;
  color: var(--white);
  font-size: 64px;
  line-height: 1.7;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#title-wrapper>p {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: var(--white);
}

label {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

--------------------------------
/* Styles defined here are disappearing :( */

input,
select {
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 43px;
  text-indent: 1rem;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: var(--white);
}

select {
  text-align: center;
  text-align-last: center;
  /* webkit*/
}

.dropdown {
  transition: .1s ease-out;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
}

option {
  text-align: left;
  /* reset to left*/
}

fieldset {
  display: flex;
  border: 0;
  gap: .5rem;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.user-input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.user-input>label {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.radio-inputs {
  flex-direction: row !important;
}

----------------------------------------------- #email-age>div:first-of-type {
  width: calc(75%);
}

#email-age>div:last-of-type {
  width: calc(25%);
}
```

```html
<div id="title-wrapper">
  <h1>Survey Form</h1>
  <p>Share your thoughts with us!</p>
</div>

<main>

  <form action="">

    <fieldset id="name-surname">

      <div class="user-input" id="name">
        <label for="user-name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="user-info" placeholder="Name" />
      </div>

      <div class="user-input" id="surname">
        <label for="user-surname">Surname</label>
        <input type="text" name="user-info" id="user-surname" placeholder="Surname">
      </div>

    </fieldset>

    <br>

    <fieldset id="email-age">

      <div class="user-input">
        <label for="">Email</label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
      </div>

      <div class="user-input">
        <label for="">Age</label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Age">
      </div>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <div class="user-input">
        <label for="dpwn">How satisfied are you with out product?</label>
        <select name="" onclick="myFunction()" id="dpwn">
          <option value="1" disabled selected>Choose an option</option>
          <option value="2">Very unsatisfied</option>
          <option value="3">Somewhat unsatisfied</option>
          <option value="4">Neutral</option>
          <option value="5">Somewhat satisfied</option>
          <option value="6">Very satisfied</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>


    <fieldset>
                    <div class="user-input radio-inputs">    
                        <input type="radio" name="frequency" id="">
                        <input type="radio" name="frequency" id="">
                        <input type="radio" name="frequency" id="">
                        <input type="radio" name="frequency" id="">
                        <input type="radio" name="frequency" id="">
                    </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</main>
```

Comment: It does put the elements in a row, but the styles get overridden for some reason

Comment: Please check these articles :https://www.google.com/amp/s/blogs.halodoc.io/best-practices-that-we-follow-to-avoid-specificity-issues/amp/

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp